# Annulus of convergence of Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, bessel-functions

For each $w \in \mathbb{C}$, consider the Laurent series centered in $z=0$
$$\exp \left(\frac{w}{2}\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)\right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}J_n(w)z^n$$ Find the annulus of convergence of the series. Does the domain depends of $w$?

What we know is that $z = 0$ is the only singular value of the function. So $|z| > 0$ but how to find an upper bound for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laurent series converges in any annulus centred at $0$ where the function is analytic.  In this case, as you say, $0$ is the only singularity, so the function is analytic on $\mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$, and the series converges for $0 < |z| < \infty$.

There is one exception: if $z=0$, the function is just $0$ (the singularity at $z=0$ being removable) and the series converges at $z=0$ as well.